# Apply and reset multiple filters on click with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to make list of products that will filter on click. But i just can't get a grasp on how to do it in react. And mainly:

1. where to make filtering function?
2. How combine and pass the data to reducer?
3. How to trigger it all with 1 button.

I'm sure it's very trivial case for an experienced devs.

repository with my code so far: https://github.com/SolidMike/react-hotels/tree/main/src/

As for now i have component  that outputs my json
and component  which contain all filters. I sadly just can't understand how to make it work with my actions and reducers :(

This is my Filter

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        filter: state.filter,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { filtersApply, filtersReset }

function Filter({ filter, filtersApply, filtersReset }) {
    console.log(filter)
    const typesOptions = [
        { value: 'appartment', label: 'Апартаменты' },
        { value: 'hotel', label: 'Отель' },
    ]
    const countriesOptions = [
        { value: 'greece', label: 'Греция' },
        { value: 'russian', label: 'Россия' },
        { value: 'ukraine', label: 'Украина' },
    ]
    const [types, setTypes] = useState([])
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

    const handleOnChangeCountries = (selectedOption) => {
        setCountries(selectedOption)
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption)
    }

    const handleOnChangeTypes = (selectedOption) => {
        setTypes(selectedOption)
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="filter__country">
                <Select
                    defaultValue={countries}
                    onChange={handleOnChangeCountries}
                    options={countriesOptions}
                />
            </div>
            <label for="type">
                Тип
                <Select
                    defaultValue={types}
                    options={typesOptions}
                    onChange={handleOnChangeTypes}
                    isMulti
                />
            </label>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Количество звезд</legend>
                <label for="one_star">
                    1 звезда
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="rating"
                        id="one_star"
                        value="1"
                    />
                </label>
                <label for="two_stars">
                    2 звезды
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="rating"
                        id="two_stars"
                        value="2"
                    />
                </label>
                <label for="three_stars">
                    3 звезды
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="rating"
                        id="three_stars"
                        value="3"
                    />
                </label>
                <label for="four_stars">
                    4 звезды
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="rating"
                        id="four_stars"
                        value="4"
                    />
                </label>
                <label for="five_stars">
                    5 звезд
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name="rating"
                        id="five_stars"
                        value="5"
                    />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <button
                className="filter__apply"
                onClick={() => {
                    filtersApply({ name: 'countryFilter', value: countries })
                }}
            >
                Применить фильтр
            </button>
            <button className="filter__reset" onClick={filtersReset}>
                Очистить фильтр
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filter)
```

reducer.js Should i even put array in initial state, i'm not sure.

```js
let initialState = {
    hotels: [
        {
            name: 'Marina Inn',
            country: 'Греция',
            address: 'Фалираки, Родос, Греция',
            stars: 4,
            type: 'Отель',
            description:
                'Этот 4-звездочный отель расположен в центре города. На его территории есть бассейн с террасой и сауна. Из номеров открывается вид на море или на средневековый город.',
            services: [
                'Пляж',
                'Кондиционер',
                'Открытый бассейн',
                'Бесплатная парковка',
                'Бесплатный WiFi',
                'Вид на море',
                'Бесплатный завтрак',
            ],
            min_price: 2789.0,
            currency: 'RUR',
            rating: 4.5,
            reviews_amount: 18,
            last_review:
                'Отличное расположение. Вкусный завтрак. Отдыхали с детьми - все понравилось.',
        },
        {
            name: 'Mondrian Suites',
            country: 'Греция',
            address: 'Фалираки, Родос, Греция',
            stars: 5,
            type: 'Апартаменты',
            description:
                'Из окон открывается вид на город.К услугам гостей номера-студио с балконом и чайником в 2,7 км от пляжа.',
            services: [
                'Пляж',
                'Кондиционер',
                'Открытый бассейн',
                'Платная парковка',
                'Бесплатный WiFi',
                'Вид на море',
            ],
            min_price: 3245.2,
            currency: 'RUR',
            rating: 5,
            reviews_amount: 4,
            last_review:
                'Потрясающее место, в номере есть все необходимое. Красивый вид на море.',
        },
        {
            name: 'Sunny Appartments',
            country: 'Греция',
            address: 'Родос, Родос, Греция',
            stars: 2,
            type: 'Апартаменты',
            description:
                'Все номера и апартаменты оборудованы кондиционером и телевизором с плоским экраном. Также в распоряжении гостей тостер и чайник.',
            services: [
                'Пляж',
                'Кондиционер',
                'Бесплатная парковка',
                'Бесплатный WiFi',
            ],
            min_price: 1153.0,
            currency: 'RUR',
            rating: 2.4,
            reviews_amount: 36,
            last_review:
                'Бассейн очень маленький. Кормят невкусно. Больше не поедем.',
        },
        {
            name: 'Super All Inclusive Hotel',
            country: 'Греция',
            address: 'Родос, Родос, Греция',
            stars: 4,
            type: 'Отель',
            description:
                'Все номера оснащены телевизором с плоским экраном. Из некоторых номеров открывается вид на море или город.',
            services: [
                'Пляж',
                'Кондиционер',
                'Открытый бассейн',
                'Бесплатный WiFi',
                'Вид на море',
                'Бесплатный завтрак',
            ],
            min_price: 3689.0,
            currency: 'RUR',
            rating: 4.1,
            reviews_amount: 14,
            last_review:
                'Недалёко от пляжа и старого города, вокруг много разных магазинчиков',
        },
        {
            name: 'Adams Hotel',
            country: 'Греция',
            address: 'Родос, Родос, Греция',
            stars: 3,
            type: 'Отель',
            description:
                'Отель расположен всего в 100 метрах от пляжа и в 5-ти минутах ходьбы от исторической части города, недалеко от всех основных достопримечательностей. Из отеля открывается вид на море. К услугам гостей спокойный открытый бассейн.',
            services: [
                'Пляж',
                'Кондиционер',
                'Открытый бассейн',
                'Бесплатная парковка',
                'Бесплатный WiFi',
                'Бесплатный завтрак',
            ],
            min_price: 1896.0,
            currency: 'RUR',
            rating: 0,
            reviews_amount: 0,
            last_review: '',
        },
    ],
    countryFilter: [],
    typeFilter: [],
    starsFilter: [],
    reviewsAmountFilter: null,
}

export const FiltersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FILTER_UPDATE': {
            console.log(action.payload)
            const { name, value } = action.payload
            return { ...state, [name]: value }
        }
        case 'FILTER_RESET': {
            return initialState
        }
        default:
            return initialState
    }
}
```

and my actions.js

```js
export const filtersApply = (payload) => ({
    type: 'FILTER_UPDATE',
    payload,
})

export const filtersReset = () => ({
    type: 'FILTER_RESET',
})
```

Comment: Can you please paste the relevant code here? As I understand as of now, you already have a list of products in your local variable. On click of a button, you need to filter some items and set them to the store. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the patterns that I extensively use, and not only  with redux, is keeping lists in two state variables. First one is hash map of all entities mapped by some identifier, and another one is list of identifiers. For example, you have list of hotels. I would do it like this:

```js
let initialState = {
  hotels: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Marina Inn",
      country: "Греция",
      address: "Фалираки, Родос, Греция",
      stars: 4,
      type: "Отель",
      description:
        "Этот 4-звездочный отель расположен в центре города. На его территории есть бассейн с террасой и сауна. Из номеров открывается вид на море или на средневековый город.",
      services: [
        "Пляж",
        "Кондиционер",
        "Открытый бассейн",
        "Бесплатная парковка",
        "Бесплатный WiFi",
        "Вид на море",
        "Бесплатный завтрак",
      ],
      min_price: 2789.0,
      currency: "RUR",
      rating: 4.5,
      reviews_amount: 18,
      last_review:
        "Отличное расположение. Вкусный завтрак. Отдыхали с детьми - все понравилось.",
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: "Mondrian Suites",
      country: "Греция",
      address: "Фалираки, Родос, Греция",
      stars: 5,
      type: "Апартаменты",
      description:
        "Из окон открывается вид на город.К услугам гостей номера-студио с балконом и чайником в 2,7 км от пляжа.",
      services: [
        "Пляж",
        "Кондиционер",
        "Открытый бассейн",
        "Платная парковка",
        "Бесплатный WiFi",
        "Вид на море",
      ],
      min_price: 3245.2,
      currency: "RUR",
      rating: 5,
      reviews_amount: 4,
      last_review:
        "Потрясающее место, в номере есть все необходимое. Красивый вид на море.",
    },
    3: {
      name: "Sunny Appartments",
      country: "Греция",
      address: "Родос, Родос, Греция",
      stars: 2,
      type: "Апартаменты",
      description:
        "Все номера и апартаменты оборудованы кондиционером и телевизором с плоским экраном. Также в распоряжении гостей тостер и чайник.",
      services: [
        "Пляж",
        "Кондиционер",
        "Бесплатная парковка",
        "Бесплатный WiFi",
      ],
      min_price: 1153.0,
      currency: "RUR",
      rating: 2.4,
      reviews_amount: 36,
      last_review:
        "Бассейн очень маленький. Кормят невкусно. Больше не поедем.",
    },
    4: {
      name: "Super All Inclusive Hotel",
      country: "Греция",
      address: "Родос, Родос, Греция",
      stars: 4,
      type: "Отель",
      description:
        "Все номера оснащены телевизором с плоским экраном. Из некоторых номеров открывается вид на море или город.",
      services: [
        "Пляж",
        "Кондиционер",
        "Открытый бассейн",
        "Бесплатный WiFi",
        "Вид на море",
        "Бесплатный завтрак",
      ],
      min_price: 3689.0,
      currency: "RUR",
      rating: 4.1,
      reviews_amount: 14,
      last_review:
        "Недалёко от пляжа и старого города, вокруг много разных магазинчиков",
    },
    5: {
      name: "Adams Hotel",
      country: "Греция",
      address: "Родос, Родос, Греция",
      stars: 3,
      type: "Отель",
      description:
        "Отель расположен всего в 100 метрах от пляжа и в 5-ти минутах ходьбы от исторической части города, недалеко от всех основных достопримечательностей. Из отеля открывается вид на море. К услугам гостей спокойный открытый бассейн.",
      services: [
        "Пляж",
        "Кондиционер",
        "Открытый бассейн",
        "Бесплатная парковка",
        "Бесплатный WiFi",
        "Бесплатный завтрак",
      ],
      min_price: 1896.0,
      currency: "RUR",
      rating: 0,
      reviews_amount: 0,
      last_review: "",
    },
  },
  ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  countryFilter: [],
  typeFilter: [],
  starsFilter: [],
  reviewsAmountFilter: null,
};
```

Now, depending on various factors I can perform filtering and sorting either inside redux, or in component where I render them. Anyway, all I have to sort is array of IDs, and I can leave actual list unchanged. For example, I want to filter all by range of stars. Reducer might look like this:

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, event) {
  if (event.type === "FILTER_UPDATE") {
    // get fresh ids list
    let ids = Object.keys(state.hotels);
    let filteredAndSortedIds = ids
      .filter((id) => {
        let hotel = state.hotels[id];
        // filter on parameters and return true or false
      })
      .sort((id1, id2) => {
        /* sort */
      });
    // here you also can set filters and sorts if needed
    return { ...state, ids: filteredAndSortedIds };
  }
  if (event.type === "FILTER_RESET") {
    let ids = Object.keys(state.hotels).sort((id1, id2) => {
      /* perform default sort to get consistent results */
    });
    // here you also can set default values for filters and sots
    return { ...state, ids };
  }
}
```

When you need to add another hotel, you add new entry to your `hotels` map and new entry in `ids` array.

You can also perform such operations not inside redux, but inside component render. You will need to be careful here so you don't render what you don't want to. In some cases it can affect performance.

To send filters values to redux, you already have what you need. Just extend the object to include all values: `dispatch(filterApply({'selectedCountries': countries, 'selectedTypes': types}))` and so on. Since you send them all to redux you might want to keep them in local state and not save into redux storage to avoid duplicating and performing synchronization, but his is up to you. In either case, you will have to reset your states to initial inside onClick handler, like this:

```js
const [types, setTypes] = useState([]);
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

<button
  className="filter__reset"
  onClick={() => {
    filtersReset();
    setTypes([]);
    setCountries([]);
  }}
>
  Очистить фильтр
</button>;
```

Comment: I see, feels kinda strange to add id's manuly.

Comment: You can use whatever unique value you have. If you are certain that hotel names have no duplicates (in my experience it is sometimes not true), you can use them. You can also use `nanoid` or `lodash/uniqueid` to set ids on initialization or when you load hotels from server.

Comment: Thx a lot, i managed to make filters work. But how do i pass changed filtered array to my HotelList component. I tryed to do it like this

Comment: Save them to redux state and `useSelector` to get them anywhere you need

Comment: Oh i made it with mapStateToProps.I'm just curious, can i somehow leave initial state of filteredArray empty and show hotels initially in my component, and then only when filter is set change it to filled filteredArray?

Comment: Let's dig into theory a bit. You have The State. It is all the data that you feed into react, including redux state, local components state, props and data from Context API. There is always some "initial" state where you start. Through a lifetime of your application your state changes. Goal of "state management" is not to properly store your current state (this is secondary), but to properly transition from one state to another. On top level you have "Not filtered" state and "Filtered" state. Your goal is to first render "Not Filtered", and then  properly transition to "Filtered" and back.

Comment: Can i ask you last question pls. How do i clear input fields on reset? I tried this `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach(
    input => (input.value = "")
  );` in reducer and in onClick function but it doesn't work

Comment: When you are using react, you should avoid interacting with DOM tree directly if it is possible. In _most_ cases it is possible. In your case, you need to use [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and change state values to change input values.